# Can you move backwards 4 spaces right outside of the safety zone?

Tags: sorry

In Sorry, can I move a pawn that is right outside my start, then pick a move backward 4 spaces card to right outside my safety zone?

Comment: @GendoIkari the linked questions asks if you can move into the safety zone (you can't -- that's not backwards); this asks if you can move to just outside it (you can)

Answer (score 9):

Yes. From the [rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Sorry.PDF), under "Moving Backwards":

> If you have successfully moved a pawn backwards at least two spaces beyond your own START space, you may, *on a subsequent turn*, move into your own SAFETY ZONE without moving all the way around the board.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for sure, that's the best!

Comment: Additionally, if this your frst 3 pawns are already in the Safety Zone you earn the right to say "Nya nya nya Nya-nya" to your opponents for the rest of the day.

Comment: Because the only thing worse than playing a game with all luck is having a poor sport "win"

Comment: If you think "Sorry" is all luck, let's play for money.