# sorry! Move backward 4 card, can you move a piece from start?

Tags: sorry

Can you move a piece from start with a backwards 4 card?

Comment: See [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/27727/can-you-move-backwards-4-spaces-right-outside-of-the-safety-zone?rq=1) - you have to be at least two spaces beyond the START zone.

Comment: @BJMyers It sounds like you're interpreting that answer incorrectly: you are allowed to move a piece backwards 4 from start or anywhere else. _On a subsequent turn_, _if_ you have moved backwards at least 2 from start - i.e. if Safety is now "ahead" of you rather than behind you (note that it's 2 spaces away from start) - then you are allowed to move forward into Safety.

Comment: @BenjaminCosman Yep, you're correct.  My bad. :)

Comment: @BJMyers makes a good point in his answer below: by "start" do you mean what the game calls START or do you mean the track space right outside it? To get a pawn from START onto the track, you need a 1 or 2.

Comment: Retracting my duplicate vote. The other question is about a pawn that's already moved out of start.

Answer (score 3):

**No**.  From the [official rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Sorry.PDF) (emphasis mine):

> To move a pawn from your START out onto the track, you must draw either a 1 or a 2... **You may not start a pawn out with any other cards.**

Comment: I'd give good odds that OP intended to ask about moving backwards from the space right outside of START to bypass going around the board, because that's what _everyone_ asks when they learn this game (with good reason: it's an extraordinarily powerful move). Nonetheless, +1 for noticing that OP _might_ be asking a different question.